# SelectionSort and for loop

Tags: java, arrays, selection

I have a question regarding SelectionSort.

Please, take a look at my Code:

```
public static int[] sortiert(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[i]) {
                int speicher = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = speicher;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
```

Can you please tell me why I have j = i + 1 in the second for-loop?
It bothers me...

array.length - 1 in the first loop is clear.

It would be nice to get an answer detailed

Comment: You should add the programming language as a tag in your question.

Comment: Otherwise you would have `i==j` in the beginning of the second for-loop. Then you would test an element against itself. Not really what you need.

Comment: @ Takit Isy
Added. Thanks!

@ kvantour
Honestly.. it is still not clear..

Does it mean an element from the first loop in the second loop and so on?
So it continues until the end of the array?

If yes, why does j = i++ not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class SelectionSort
{
    static int min;
    public static void Sort(int[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                min = j;
                if (data[i] < data[j])
                    Swap(x: ref data[i], y: ref data[min]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Swap(ref int x, ref int y)
    {
        x = x+y;
        y = x-y;
        x = x-y;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give a bit explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The `sortiert` method is running through the array multiple times. With every pair of elements, if the second element (the one later in the list) is greater than the first element (`if (array[j] > array[i])`), then it swaps the two elements, such that eventually the list will be sorted in decreasing order.

The `i` index represents the "first value" being compared above and the `j` index represents the "second value" being compared above. Thus, `j` will always start at `i+1` as it must always be **after** the first value in the list. If `j = i` in the for loop, then you would be checking `array[i] > array[i]` because `j = i` in that case; since a number is never *strictly* less than itself, this would always return `false` and is thus an unnecessary operation.